# Unable to access Sinatra app on host machine with Vagrant forwarded ports

Tags: ruby, http, ubuntu, sinatra, vagrant

After starting my Sinatra application with both `ruby app.rb` and `foreman start` I am unable to access my application with localhost and the respective port on my host machine. I am also able to `curl` to the applications from within the shell of on guest machine, whereas on the host machine the `curl` request fails. As far as I know there shouldn't be a firewall in place on the guest machine because I'm using the Vagrant Ubuntu image.

My Vagrantfile is as follows:

```
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  config.vm.box = 'precise32'
  config.vm.box_url = 'http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box'
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 4567, host: 4567
end
```

Comment: This _might_ be because by default in development mode Sinatra [only listens to localhost](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration#bind---server-hostname-or-ip-address), not 0.0.0.0 (I don’t know how Vagrant handles the forwarding and how the guest sees any requests). Does using `set :bind, '0.0.0.0'` to your app make it available?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default when running in development mode, [Sinatra only listens to localhost](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#bind---server-hostname-or-ip-address), not to `0.0.0.0` (this change was made due to [security considerations](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/commit/0f9a959253bdf0c39422ffb9b60278df46ef0248)).

To allow requests from any interface, either add `set :bind, '0.0.0.0'` to your app file, or start your app with the `-o` option, e.g. `ruby myapp.rb -o 0.0.0.0`.

You may be able to set this to the actual address assigned to the guest, but I don’t know if it will be worth it.

Comment: When running via `shotgun` the `:bind` command didn't seem to work, but the `-o` option worked just fine.

Comment: @ajsharma I looked on it and saw shotgun passes host option '127.0.0.1' by default so this would override `:bind` command. [source code](https://github.com/rtomayko/shotgun/blob/master/bin/shotgun)