# Virtual Box port forwarding misery with Ruby Sinatra:4567 / Shotgun:9292

Tags: ruby, linux, sinatra, virtualbox, shotgun

I've got a VirtualBox `CentOS 7.0` Guest OS on a `Windows Ten` Host for the purposes of development, and the port forwarding simply isn't working.

I have a `NAT'd` network adapter (I can't use Bridged Adapters on this network) and to be fair I am much more comfortable with Bridged Adapters. But everything else works swimmingly. Except the ports 4567 and 9292 will not forward, while port 22 and port 80 work fine.

I have

- Added port forwarding on the client for the ports `22`,`80`,`4567`,`9292` in VirtualBox on the NAT'd adapter.
- disabled the firewalld on `CentOS 7.0` completely (and restarted) then ruled that out
- all ports work fine on local host i.e. in the vm `localhost:4567` is perfect as is `localhost:9292`
- switched of `SELINUX` on guest (for good measure)
- restarted the whole VM on host systematically every time I did a network->portforward alteration
- tried `10.0.2.15:4567` / `10.0.2.15:9292` in a vain attempt to get purchase

all the time I am ssh'd in on port `22` and port `80` works fine

Is this a traffic issue or a firewall issue, is there some sort of network filtering on the VirtualBox interface that's hidden from me?

I'd love some help.

Comment: This looks like the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250885/unable-to-access-sinatra-app-on-host-machine-with-vagrant-forwarded-ports/21270176#21270176

Comment: Thanks @matt you're right, it's a shotgun thing I'll post the answer

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: thanks for your diligence +jww, but this certainly is a development question, most notably because the linked answer was posted in SO, thanks for your diligence in this matter, perhaps I might suggest slightly more thought next time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NB: **THE CAUSE IS SHOTGUN/RUBY NOT VirtualBox nor Firewalls nor port forwarding**

@Matt fixed this... his [link in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250885/unable-to-access-sinatra-app-on-host-machine-with-vagrant-forwarded-ports/21270176#21270176) is correct, the fix to this is one of two things: (it's actually `shotgun` running ruby in development mode that causes it)

CAUSE:

- RUBY running in default `set :bind, 'localhost'` development mode. [(link)](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration#bind---server-hostname-or-ip-address)

SOLUTION:

- RUBY runs with options `set :bind, '0.0.0.0'` (can also be in the config.ru)

Good news is if you're looking to make localhost:4567 work this is your ticket, add the line `set :bind, '0.0.0.0'` to your config and you're good to go

**ANNOYINGLY IF YOU RUN SHOTGUN THIS ISN'T GOING TO BE PICKED UP**

Bad news is if you're looking to make localhost:9292 work shotgun does it's own thing here:

- in fact `shotgun` won't LOOK at those ruby configs, it'll adopt it's own boot strategy, so you have to MAKE shotgun run in `--host=0.0.0.0` mode: EG:
- `# shotgun --server=thin --port=9292 --host=0.0.0.0 config.ru`